# Let $X(t)$ be a stochastic process in $C(0,T)$

Tags: probability

Let $X(t)$ be a stochastic process in $C(0,T)$, that is a Borel probability measure on $C(0,T)$ - denote the space $(C,\mathcal F,\mu)$. Consider a topological basis $\psi_i$ for $C(0,T)$. For each $\omega\in \Omega$ we have that $\omega(t)$ is a continuous function and therefore we have that

$$\omega(t)=\sum c_i(\omega)\psi_i(t)$$

for some sequence of $c_i(\omega)$. I'm curious about the measurability of the random variables $c_i$. Obviously the $c_i$ are $\mathcal F$ measurable. But are they $\mathcal F_t$ measurable for any $t<T$? I suspect not, but I'd like a proof.

Edit: I guess I'm not even sure that they are $\mathcal F$ measurable...

Comment: Why is it obvious that they are $\mathcal F$ measurable.

Comment: Hello there, could you describe which filtration you are using?

Comment: @Kernel The natural filtration of $X(t)$.